# Ajax Receiving wrong data but PHP works fine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i submit my form normally to PHP using action=""... it works. But when i submit using AJAX, it keeps alerting "ILD"... Invalid Logging Details.
What am i doing wrong please?

**This is my form **

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return do_signIn()">
                        Username:
                        <input id="#user" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username" name="username" />
                        Password:
                        <input id="#pass" type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                        <br />
                        <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Login" name="login"/> <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Forget Password?</a></span>
                        <br /><br />
                        <p id="error-area"></p>
                    </form>
```

** Below is my AJAX JQUERY **

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function do_signIn() {
            var username = $("#user").val();
            var password = $("#pass").val();
            var login = $("#login").val();
            if(username!="" && password!=""){
                $("#error-area").html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Loading...");
                $.ajax
            ({
            type:'post',
            url:'b-sign-in.php',
            data:{
                    do_signIn:"b-sign-in",
                    username:username,
                    password:password,
                    login:login,
            },
                    success:function(response) {
            if(response=="VA"){
                    alert("Verify Your Account" + response);
                    //window.location.href="";
            }else if(response=="SUCCESS"){
                    alert("Success! You are In");
                    //window.location.href="";
            }else if(response=="ELI"){
                    alert("Error Loggin In");
                    //window.location.href="";
            }else if(response=="ILD"){
                    alert(response);
                    //window.location.href="";
            }else{
            $("#error-area").html("Something Went Wrong");
            alert(response);
            //$("#error-area").slideUp(5000);
            }
            }
            });
            }else{
            $("#error-area").html("Please fill all fileds!");
            //$("#error-area").slideUp(5000);
            }       
            return false;
            }
</script>
```

and ** Here is my PHP **

```
   if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="Login"){      
        //check user input
        $username = sanitizeMySQL($con, $_POST['username']);
        $password = sanitizeMySQL($con, $_POST['password']);

        //harsh the password
        //Harsh the password
        $harshQuery = "SELECT info_value FROM b_info WHERE info_name = 'siteHarsh'";
        $harshRun = mysqli_query($con, $harshQuery);
        $harshRow = mysqli_num_rows($harshRun);
        if(!$harshRow || $harshRow > 1 || $harshRow < 1){
            echo "error"; // Show An unexpected error occured
            exit();
        }else{
            $passHarsh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($harshRun);
            $harsh = $passHarsh['info_value'];
            $correctPassword = md5($harsh . $password . $harsh);
        }

        $run = "
                    SELECT * FROM b_user
                    WHERE user_name = '$username'
                    AND user_password = '$correctPassword'
                ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $run);
        $rowno = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //Check if detail match in db
        if($rowno == 1){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['loggeduser'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user_name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['user_email'];

            if($row['user_activation'] == 0){
                echo "VA"; //Verify Your Account By Entering a Valid Phone Number
                exit();
            }else if($row['user_activation'] == 1){
                echo "SUCCESS";
                exit();
            }
            else{
                echo "ELI"; //Error Logging In
                exit();
            }           
        }
        else {
            echo "ILD"; //Invalid Login Details
            exit();
        }
//When No Post of Signup or SignIn is discovered
}else {
    header("Location:". SITE_HOME);
}
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging and log debugging output in browser console. Also inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see that what is sent is what is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before, you shouldnt use the form elements like this :

you must write id="user" not id="#user". You couldnt this type on javascript get value.
this wrong:

```
<input id="#user" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username" name="username" />
```

this correct :

```
<input id="user" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username" name="username" />
```

Comment: Thank you for that observation. That is why it is very good to work with a team. I didn't see that for couple of hours. I did not even believe i can make such silly error. Thanks so much. You saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Your input-ids in your html-form are #username and #password. Remove the hashtags and it will work fine.

Comment: Where are you talking about dear @Morosko? Where are the input-ids you're talking about? Line what of which of the scripts?